# Can't send Email SMTP in ez publish 5.4

Tags: ezpublish

I can't send or receive email, i added the following settings  to the  : site.ini  located  in `D:\EasyPHP-.3.3\www\ezpublish5.4\ezpublish_legacy\settings` :

```html
Transport=sendmail
#A list of possible handlers for sending mails, use the setting Transport to specify which one to use

TransportAlias[]
TransportAlias[file]=eZFileTransport
TransportAlias[sendmail]=eZSendmailTransport
TransportAlias[smtp]=eZSMTPTransport
# Configuration for SMTP
TransportServer=smtp.gmail.com
# Connection type in SMTP: <empty>(no encryption)|ssl|sslv2|sslv3|tls
TransportConnectionType=ssl
# Default SMTP port is 25, default Secure SMTP port(SSL,TLS) is 465
TransportPort=465
TransportUser=user@server.com
TransportPassword=mypassword
SenderHost=localhost
AdminEmail=user@server.com
# The address which will be set as the From header of the e-mail, unless
# overridden by the template variable email_sender.
EmailSender=user@server.com
DebugReceiverEmail=user@server.com
```

And the configuration of Proxy :

```html
ProxyServer=**********:9090
User=user
Password=************
```

Has somebody done something similar or perhaps I have misspelled the topic search within the forum posts. Anyhow I would be very glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I've never configured a google account to send mail directly from EZ, but try this :

```
TransportServer=smtp.googlemail.com
```

the mail delivery was delayed and ended up in the gmail spam folder (i think you're emailing via eZ Publish to a gmail account).

Let me assure you this is not an eZ Publish problem as eZ Mail is stable (rock solid).

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work :

I have this error :

 [127.0.0.1] eZSMTPTransport::sendMail:
An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the smtp server: :465.
 [127.0.0.1] Timing Point: Module end 'content'

what did you use as TransportServer ? My objective is to send/to receive email no matter what the TransportServer is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set `Transport=smtp`

Comment: I've configured also Sendmail, but unfortunately it doesn't work,
I'm working on Windows 7, so i can't use this tutoriel.
My configuration is as follow :

EasyPHP-5.3.3, and  eZ Publish Community Project 2014.07.

I think the problem is that i have a proxy settings that block the mail to be send, i tried to test sending mail in a place without a proxy settings and it works fine.